# Pyspark unix_timestamp striping the last zeros while converting from datetime to unix time

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, unix-timestamp

I have the following date dataframe,

```
end_dt_time
2020-10-12 04:00:00
2020-10-11 04:00:00
2020-10-10 04:00:00
2020-10-09 04:00:00
2020-10-08 04:00:00
```

while converting these dates to unix timestamp the trailing zero are not appearing giving me incorrect time in unix.

This is what i am applying :

```
df = df.withColumn('unix', F.unix_timestamp('en_dt_time'))
```

the output is missing the last 3 zeros(000)

```
en_dt_time          unix
2020-10-12 04:00:00 1602475200
2020-10-11 04:00:00 1602388800
2020-10-10 04:00:00 1602302400
2020-10-09 04:00:00 1602216000
2020-10-08 04:00:00 1602129600
2020-10-07 04:00:00 1602043200
```

the desired output is

```
en_dt_time          unix
2020-10-12 04:00:00 1602475200000
2020-10-11 04:00:00 1602388800000
2020-10-10 04:00:00 1602302400000
2020-10-09 04:00:00 1602216000000
2020-10-08 04:00:00 1602129600000
2020-10-07 04:00:00 1602043200000
```

How can i get this precision while converting to unix timestamp?
I was able to generate this by multiplying the output with 1000

```
df = df.withColumn('unix', F.unix_timestamp('en_dt_time')*1000)
```

is this the right approach?

Comment: thats the only way I know of. I often come across where I have an epoch millisecond and need to convert it to timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct behavior. From the [function's description](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp):

> Convert time string with given pattern (‘yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss’, by default) to Unix time stamp (in **seconds**), using the default timezone and the default locale

So if you just want to get milliseconds, then you just need to convert seconds to milliseconds as you're doing right now.